# Limit the number of TCP connection I can acceptI() on WinCE

Tags: tcp, windows-ce, winsock, tcplistener

My requirements is "Limit the number of sockets I can accept() on WinCE, let's say 60 sockets".

Because I came across problem:

1. My WinCE embedded system has limited resource to handle requests from TCP. So I must limit the number of TCP connections.
2. I tried this :
     if I do not call accept() if I found I have already accepted 60 sockets. There would be serious problems on it. The device would become very slow. I am trying to debug this.
3. If I first accept() it, and then close() it, client would report error; because client believes it is misbehaving if server first accepts a TCP connection and then closes it immediately.

Could any one give me a hint about how I could do this.

I tried to read source code in the /WINCE/PRIVATE folder,I can only trace to "proxy.SOMETHING()". It seems I can not find the code of windows socket.
Could you please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Don't call `accept()` when you already have 60 open sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't call accept() connections are still established at the lower TCP/IP level, having the other side then waiting for your accept (and maybe then retrying). Even if you don't call accept() then you will still have some activities going on for each connection request and this may be the stuff that slows down your system. 
You should have a socket bound to the incoming port (and optionally address) with a listen call pending. As long as you do a listen() you are telling the system to process incoming connection requests and report them to you for an accept(). If you close that socket and don't do any listen() on it (better to close it because this will remove most of the connection management stuff) then the system load should decrease. On the other side clients will report your server as unreachable and this may be an issue because they will not be able to understand if the server is really down or just loaded by requests.

Comment: . int listen(  _In_ SOCKET s,  _In_ int    backlog ); , As I understand it ,the second parameter, backlog is the "number of the waiting connections". Can I decrease this value to minimize the consumed resources. I would like to look into the code for more. Do you know where I can read socket code of WinCE. Thanks :) Have a nice day.

Comment: 'Listen call pending' and 'close that socket and don't do any `listen()`' are both meaningless. `listen()` is not a blocking call and can't be 'pending'. Once `listen()` has been called the only way to undo it *is* to close the socket. Completing connections into the backlog queue is trivial and is certainly not 'the stuff that slows down your system'.

Comment: @Dongguo You can try decreasing that parameter, but the system can adjust it up or down, and there is no way to determine the actual value that was used. In any case it doesn't prevent you from accepting more than N connections simultaneously, as it doesn't include the connections you have already accepted and are now processing. Only you can do that, by counting accepts and closes, and not calling accept while the difference >= N.

Comment: Changing the parameter will influence the number of connection that listen will keep alive waiting for an accept. A TCP/IP connection is activated trough multiple steps. First listen, then accept. You may notice this because you get different error codes on the client side, depending on the fact that there was no listen waiting for connections or that the server did not call accept.

Comment: Having a listen call pending (meaning listen called and no connections returned) or not (closing the socket) makes a difference because incoming connections to that port are (listen) or aren't (no socket) routed up to the application level of the TCP/IP stack. This can generate some overhead and if the idea is to reduce it to the minimum closing the socket may be an option.

Comment: Thanks to all @Valter Minute